# Is it possible to select multiple objects based on mesh and not origin?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

Every now and then I will stumble across this issue when making instanced objects in a circular rotation pattern. The origins will be at the center of the arc, while the actual meshes will be a large distance away from the origin. I will then add more objects with identically positioned origins in the center of the circle (i.e. watch face). Is there a way to select the outer bolts using an equivalent of the standard <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> free-select for mesh surface instead of mesh origins?

[image: Select By Surface Illustration]

I am aware of the ability to select linked objects, this solution will not always work.

Comment: If groups are not convinient for you, I will suggest [supergrouper](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?360257-Super-Grouper) addon, with that you can select bunch of objects in one single click.

Comment: I would define a vertex group containing the instances of the outer bolts. Then the outer bolts can be selected using the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Border select seems to select by mesh surface, whereas circle and lasso select use origin positions.

Comment: Hmm . . . I need to be able to make a custom selection shape if at all possible

Comment: You could get your lower example with three border selects. If there is a difference on Z you may be able to rotate around and get it in one.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the fastest selection method, in your case, is by typing the name of the object in the outliner search bar (often a couple of type is enough)

Comment: So I could select all meshes starting with `n` characters? I have a couple dozen that I need to select